# How to subtract column values in each table row dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table that is built by jquery dynamically, i would like to subtract values in the inputs in the third column from the second column and store the value in the third column for each row created....

//Table creation

```
$('#addRow').click(function(){          
    table= $('.tg-table-light > tbody');
    newRow =  "<tr class='tg-even'><td><div align='center'>"+i+"</div></td>\n\
                   <td><input type='text' id='' name='capsdata1[]' size='20' class='num' required tabindex='1'/></td>\n\
                   <td><input type='text' id='' name='capsdata2[]' size='20' class='num1' required tabindex='1'/></td>\n\
                   <td><input type='text' id='' name='capsdata3[]' size='20' class='num2' readonly tabindex='1'/></td>\n\
                   <td><button id='remRow'>-Remove</button></td>\n\
               </tr>";
               i++; 
               $('.tg-table-light > tbody tr:last').before( $(newRow) );         
       return false;
    });

  //This is my subtraction code
  $(".tg-table-light >tbody input.num1").keyup(function() {
        value1 = $(this).closest("tr").find("input.num").val();
        value2 = $(this).closest("tr").find("input.num1").val();
        $(this).closest("tr").find("input.num2").val(value1 - value2);
  }
```

suggestions

Answer (score 0):

*As you are creating elements dynamically.*

You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on(event,selector,event_handler)
```

*Example*

```
$(".tg-table-light >tbody").on('click', 'input.num1', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    // Conver your variables to numbers, notice +
    var value1 = +tr.find("input.num").val(); 
    var value2 = +tr.find("input.num1").val();
    tr.find("input.num2").val(value1 - value2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

and for value2 directly use $(this).val()

```
$(".tg-table-light >tbody input.num1").keyup(function() {
        value1 = $(this).closest("tr").find("input.num").val();
        value2 = $(this).val();
        $(this).closest("tr").find("input.num2").val(value1 - value2); 
});
```